# Scrape data from flash page using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from this page:

http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/tournaments/brisbane-international-presented-by-suncorp/339/2016/match-stats/r975/f324/match-stats?

If I try to scrape the name of the players using the css selector and the usual rvest syntax:

```
names <- read_html("http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/tournaments/brisbane-international-presented-by-suncorp/339/2016/match-stats/r975/f324/match-stats?") %>% 
html_nodes(".scoring-player-name") %>% sapply(html_text)
```

everything goes well.

Unfortunately if I try to scrape the statistics below (first serve pts won, ..) 
using the selector `.stat-breakdown span` I am not able to retrieve any data.

I know rvest is generally not recommended to scrape pages created dynamically, however I don't understand why some data are scraped and some not.

Comment: Looks like data you are looking for is in JSON object within this tag "//script[@id='matchStatsData']" and upon request it is loaded into table. There are obviously ways to play around with regex but it is messy.

Comment: No way to do it (maybe using Rselenium) ? I am willing to spend time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Rvest. If you follow the code below you should get to the format which is in the picture basically a string which you could transform to dataframe based on separators :, .

This Tag also contains more information than it was displayed in UI of webpage.
I can try also RSelenium but need to get my other PC. So I would let you know if RSelenium worked for me.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(stringr)

url<-"http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/tournaments/brisbane-international-presented-by-suncorp/339/2016/match-stats/r975/f324/match-stats?"
url2<-getURL(url)
parsed<-htmlParse(url2)
# get messi data from tag
step1<-xpathSApply(parsed,"//script[@id='matchStatsData']",xmlValue)
# removing some unwanted characters
step2<-str_replace_all(step1,"\r\n","")
step3<-str_replace_all(step2,"\t","")
step4<-str_replace_all(step3,"[[{}]\"]","")
```

Output then is a string like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have been able to extract the informations I needed. Just one last thing, I would like to become more confident with scraping, can you redirect me to some guide about how you extracted those informations (or at least that can be useful for those purposes)?

Comment: You are welcome. As a resource for learning about the subject I found on the internet a book Automated data collection with R which is very comprehensive and truly great resource.  Otherwise if i don't succeed with getting data based on inspecting elements I go to network tab in chrome developer tools and look under XHR a DOC for files which can include data. Often there might be url pointing to these files or data is included in preview...........hard to define exact way how to go about it

Comment: Don't worry I know there is no ready recipe but that book is what I was looking for